# Json Extract vs Json Extract Scalar

Tags: arrays, json, hive, apache-pig

I have a json string where I need to extract an array.

```
a='{"player":{"username":"user1","partner_Name":[{"firstname":"my_first"},{"lastname":"my_last"}],"characteristics":{"race":"Human","class":"Warlock","subclass":"Dawnblade","power":300,"playercountry":"USA"}}}'
```

`JsonExtractScalar(a, '$.player.username')` It returns `user1`

But I do `JsonExtractScalar(a, '$.player.player_Name')` it returns `null`.

Meanwhile `JsonExtract(a, '$.player.username')` this returns `[{"firstname":"my_first"},{"lastname":"my_last"}]`

I want to understand what is the difference between them and when to use which one?

Answer (score 2):

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/extracting-data-from-JSON.html

> To extract the scalar value from the JSON string, use the json_extract_scalar function. It is similar to json_extract, but returns only scalar values (Boolean, number, or string).
>
> Note: Do not use the json_extract_scalar function on arrays, maps, or structs.

Answer (score -2):

If you want to extract to an array then simply use

```
JSON.parse(a);
```

no need to do extra efforts.